# Need help writing python code for an assignment

Tags: python

I have an assignment to and I don't understand how to do it at all. Here is the question:

> Write a program that counts and displays the number of words and the number of sentences in the following paragraph:
>
> *A Turing machine is a device that manipulates symbols on a strip of tape according to a table of rules. Despite its simplicity, a Turing machine can be adapted to simulate the logic of any computer algorithm, and is particularly useful in explaining the functions of a CPU inside a computer. The "Turing" machine was described by Alan Turing in 1936, who called it an "a(utomatic)-machine". The Turing machine is not intended as a practical computing technology, but rather as a hypothetical device representing a computing machine. Turing machines help computer scientists understand the limits of mechanical computation.*

And here is what i have written already:

```
def main():
    def word_count(str):
        counts = dict()
        words = str.split()

        for word in words:
            if word in counts:
                counts[word] +=1
            else:
                counts[word] = 1

        return counts
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question, exactly? This seems like it should work, although I would `strip` punctuation like periods `'.'` for the sake of completeness...

Comment: We don't offer help with homework assignments. But, I hate being utterly unhelpful. Word counting exercises like this are discussed far and wide on the 'net. There are also innumerable introductions to Python. Just Google. :)

Comment: @BillBell homework questions are welcome as long as they stick to the [guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Emma: you should probably also take a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you learned regular expressions and the `re` module? That's the easiest way to get words without things like commas and periods stuck to them.

Comment: I tested the codes and it works in my computer.  The only thing you need to notice is that, you have to call Main() in your codes.

Comment: I think this is a well-written question. Homework assignments are okay to post as long as there is existing code posted that you are trying to get to work.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why the dict is necessary. Unless the question has some other part I can't see, it just asks for the number of words and sentences in the paragraph. Can you not just split the paragraph by spaces and get the `len()` of the list for the words and the same thing for sentences except split by '.' ?

Comment: My apologies, Emma!

Comment: Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga.

Comment: Thanks, @tdelaney.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution, in my opinion, without using the `re` module is implementing the following functions:

```
def getWordCount(self):
    return len(self.split())
def getSentenceCount(self):
    return self.count(".")
print("Word count:",getWordCount(str),"\nSentence Count:",getSentenceCount(str))
```

This prints:

```
Word count: 98 
Sentence Count: 5
```

**Note:** For sentences, this assumes that the last sentence ends with a dot(`.`) and there are no other dots expect for the ones delimiting sentences.

#### Alternative to the sentence counter:

```
def getSentenceCount(self):
        return len(self.split("."))-1
```

---

#### Handling `!`, `?`, `;` and `...`

For handling occurences of the characters mentioned above, you should do something like this, and repeat that for every possible character to be handled:

```
def getSentenceCount(self):
    st=self.replace("?",".").replace("!",".").replace("...",".").replace(";",".").replace("?!",".")
    return st.count(".")
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this one suits well. Good one.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bhargav

Answer (score 1):

yet another regex solution that separates out punctuation and ignores case when counting words. I'm not sure whether you want total word count or unique word count, so I did both...

I use a reqular expression `r"\w+"` to find words and `collections.Counter` to count the words.

```
import collections
import re

text = """A Turing machine is a device that manipulates symbols on a strip of tape according to a table of rules. Despite its simplicity, a Turing machine can be adapted to simulate the logic of any computer algorithm, and is particularly useful in explaining the functions of a CPU inside a computer. The "Turing" machine was described by Alan Turing in 1936, who called it an "a(utomatic)-machine". The Turing machine is not intended as a practical computing technology, but rather as a hypothetical device representing a computing machine. Turing machines help computer scientists understand the limits of mechanical computation."""

print("Number of words:", sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r"\w+", text)))
unique_words = collections.Counter(match.group(0).lower() for match in re.finditer(r"\w+", text))
print("Number of unique words:", len(unique_words))
print("Unique words:", ', '.join(sorted(unique_words)))
print("Number of sentences:", sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r"\.", text)))
```

Running it results in...

```
$ python3 test.py
Number of words: 100
Number of unique words: 63
Unique words: 1936, a, according, adapted, alan, algorithm, an, and, any, as, be, but, by, called, can, computation, computer, computing, cpu, described, despite, device, explaining, functions, help, hypothetical, in, inside, intended, is, it, its, limits, logic, machine, machines, manipulates, mechanical, not, of, on, particularly, practical, rather, representing, rules, scientists, simplicity, simulate, strip, symbols, table, tape, technology, that, the, to, turing, understand, useful, utomatic, was, who
Number of sentences: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a wonderfull library in python called "nltk" for processing natural language.
It contains various functions for handling text, one of which is called a "sentence_tokenize".
If you can use external libraries you can install it easily.

Open cmd and run `pip install nltk`
After that create a script with the following code and run it:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

This will open a window like this one:
[image]

Just press on download and wait for it to finish.

After that you can use  nltk library for text / natural language processing.

Create the script with the following code and run it:

```
  import nltk


text = """A Turing machine is a device that manipulates symbols on a strip of tape according to a table of rules.
 Despite its simplicity, a Turing machine can be adapted to simulate the logic of any computer algorithm, and is particularly useful in explaining the functions of a CPU inside a computer. 
 The "Turing" machine was described by Alan Turing in 1936, who called it an "a(utomatic)-machine". 
 The Turing machine is not intended as a practical computing technology, but rather as a hypothetical device representing a computing machine.
 Turing machines help computer scientists understand the limits of mechanical computation.
 """

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text) # this function will "tokenize" the text and pull all the sentences from it into a list

words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

print("Number of sentences: " + len(sentences))
print("Number of words: " + len(words))
```

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to be looking for some kind of explanation, at least in part. Since you appear to be new to Python I will stay with simpler possibilities.

Many Python programs have this basic structure. (Not all.)

```
def main():
    # do something
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I suspect that you have been properly taught part of this only.

The *main* function can call other functions within itself to do specific tasks. *main* can be made to accept input from its caller, in this case, the paragraph to be assessed. These are the main things I wanted to mention.

But finally, perhaps the simplest way of identifying and counting words (in Python) is to split a string on its blanks and note the length of the resulting array. No PhD necessary. This might stumble on 'automatic-machine'; however, so might a human-being.

```
def main(input):
    print ('word count:', word_count(input))
    print ('sentence count:', sentence_count(input))
    return

def word_count(str):
    a_count = len(str.split())
    return a_count

def sentence_count(str):
    # count the sentences
    a_count = None
    return a_count

if __name__ == '__main__':

    paragraph ='''A Turing machine is a device that manipulates symbols on a strip of tape according to a table of rules. Despite its simplicity, a Turing machine can be adapted to simulate the logic of any computer algorithm, and is particularly useful in explaining the functions of a CPU inside a computer. The "Turing" machine was described by Alan Turing in 1936, who called it an "a(utomatic)-machine". The Turing machine is not intended as a practical computing technology, but rather as a hypothetical device representing a computing machine. Turing machines help computer scientists understand the limits of mechanical computation.'''
    main(paragraph)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Python script (let's call it ./counter.py) would do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fileinput
import re

words =0
sents =0

for line in fileinput.input():
        words += len(line.split())
        sents += len(re.findall("(!\?)|(\.\.\.)|[\.?!]", line))

print 'Total words:     ', words
print 'Total sentances: ', sents
```

Assuming the paragraph is stored in ./test.txt file:

```
monty:python%> cat ./test.txt | ./counters.py
Total words:      98
Total sentances:  5
monty:python%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
 example_string = "This is an example string. it is cool." # This would be your very long string of text.

 words = example_string.split(" ") #splits the string around every whitespace character
 words = words.trim() #just in case there's extra whitespace

 sentences = example.split(".") #splits the string around every "." character
 sentences = sentences.trim() #just in case there's extra whitespace

 numOfSentences = len(sentences) #gets the length of the array (number of sentences as an int
 numOfWords = len(words) #gets the length of the array (number of sentences as an int

 print(numOfWords)
 print(numOfSentences)
```

Output should be:

```
 8
 2
```